# ListPointPlot3D syntax for missing data

Tags: plotting, syntax, missing

I have to plot different families of data some of which might be empty. If the data happens to be empty I want to automatically preserve the ordering of the `PlotStyle`'s. For ListPlot this is easy to do. It takes for example the following input

```
ListPlot[{{Missing[]}, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}}]
```

and correctly applies the second style to the second list of points while plotting nothing for the Missing data.

However, for ListPointPlot3D I cannot figure out the equivalent. (Note I do not want to replace missing entries with e.g. Nothing[] or remove them, because then the data sets will not be ordered correctly with the styles provided in `PlotStyle`.)

For example the following returns an error that the dataset is invalid:

```
ListPointPlot3D[{Missing[], {{1, 3, 3}, {2, 4, 4}}}]
```

How can I easily deal with plotting list which might be empty/Missing?

Answer (score 0):

Oops, that was easy, just enter an empty list instead of `Missing[]`:

```
ListPointPlot3D[{{}, {{1, 3, 3}, {2, 4, 4}}}]
```

Comment: Since he probably doesn't want to do manual replacement, I suggest including an automatic way, for example: `data = {Missing[], {{1, 3, 3}, {2, 4, 4}}}; ListPointPlot3D[data /. Missing[] -> Nothing]`

Comment: Haha, actually I am the OP, I stumbled on the solution just after posting. Note that your suggestion is not what I want. It is important to preserve something so that the ordering of the styles remains correct. Therefore the automatic replacement version would be: `data = {Missing[], {{1, 3, 3}, {2, 4, 4}}}; ListPointPlot3D[
 data /. Missing[] -> {}]`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I wasn't paying attention :)